# Using CameraSource class instead of SurfaceHolder.Callback

Tags: opencv, google-api, computer-vision, android

In my android application I have to use camera to scan some documents. Also I need to implement Google Mobile Vision (OCR) function to get the text from the doc. Specifically, I need that OCR in scanning activity because I need to identify the document type by reading the header.

I have tried capturing document edges using OpenCV and it was success. I have few clarifications in this stage for further development.

1. I have came across 2 ways to use camera, `CameraSource` and `SurfaceHolder.Callback`. What are the differences and drwabacks between those two?
2. Can I use `CameraSource` with OpenCV to overlay the edges realtime?